# Azure Windows VM with Azure AD Authentication

Tags: sql-server, windows, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-vm-templates

I am building a few VMs in Azure

- Windows Server Data Center 2019
- Windows Server 2019 with SQL Server 2019 Enterprise
- Windows Server 2019 with SQL Server 2019 Developer

I want these VMs to be authenticated using my Azure AD (available in the same subscription). We had originally signed up for Office 365 so we got the Azure AD for free (or at least that is how it was explained to me).

We have some end users and admins who will be using their personal laptops to remote login to these VMs.
How can I configure these VMs to authenticate using the Azure AD?

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/join-windows-vm#join-the-vm-to-the-managed-domain) or [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-domain-join-existing) answer your question ? Be aware there is a limit on how many objects a user can join to a domain, so maybe you need to increase that aswell.

Comment: Is this document helpful? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows